# How to arrange tiles in vertical rows (Windows 8.1)?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm trying to arrange tiles in Windows 8.1 below each other but they always arrange themselfs next to each other.

I have i. e. a group of tiles with four columns - the first two columns have five tiles each (= full height of the Start screen), the next two columns have two tiles each. I want to have the two tiles from the last column under the the two tiles from the third column so that there are altogether only three columns. However, it is impossible to get the two tiles from the last column below the two tiles from the third column - they flip around but refuse to be in one column but remain in two columns instead.

In another group I have just 5 tiles which would fit perfectly fine in one column. However, Windows 8.1 keeps them stubbornly in two columns with three tiles in the first and two tiles in the second column.

How can I get the tiles below each other?

Comment: You can't edit the start screen the way you want this.